# Boto3 API for cloudwatch - get_metrics_statistics returns empty array

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to call cloudwatch API using boto3, and it seems to be going through well. But the data returned is an empty array [], even with a 200 response. What am I missing ?

```
cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace='AWS/ELB',
        MetricName='Latency',
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name' : 'LoadBalancerName',
                'Value' : '********'
            }
        ],  
        StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=600),
        EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
        Period=60,
        Statistics=['Average', 'Maximum']
)

{u'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'f631c9d6-b6d4-11e8-9b60-89ddf4935382', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'f631c9d6-b6d4-11e8-9b60-89ddf4935382', 'date': 'Wed, 12 Sep 2018 21:44:00 GMT', 'content-length': '330', 'content-type': 'text/xml'}}, u'Label': 'Latency'}
```

I tried other APIs on boto3, to verify the connection , and I do get a valid response.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Presumably this is actually a classic ELB. Can you graph the metrics in the AWS CloudWatch console? Perhaps broaden the time range?

Comment: I tried a couple of them, when I log onto my cloudwatch/monitoring, I can see the data

Comment: I'm going to guess you are targeting the wrong AWS region or using the wrong AWS account (perhaps mistakenly provided credentials for a different account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out for some reason the AWS-SDK was adding a month to my startDateTime and EndDateTime parameters. I used

```
 AWS.config.logger = console;
```

in my code, which helped me see the logs, and that confirmed that it was looking a month ahead. I update my code to take a month earlier, and it seems to run fine now.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely to me that the SDK has a bug of this magnitude. Any chance that you have made an off-by-one error in your use of date/time?

Answer (score 1):

empty array is an acceptable returned value - when the data is not available:

- for the time range
- for the unit
- for the period
- for the statistic

Are you able to see some data in the CloudWatch Console if you request the same set of statistics/period/time range for that metric?

Comment: I ran aws-cli command , and then the python boto3 api method call. The aws-cli commaned returned a full array, python call returned an empty array. Let me post the queries I ran in the next comments.

Comment: AWS-CLI command that I ran - 


aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2018-08-01T23:18:00Z --end-time 2018-09-09T23:18:00Z --period 3600 --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-*

Comment: Python call - 

cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    MetricName='CPUUtilization”',
    Dimensions=[{
            'Name' : 'InstanceId',
            'Value' : 'i-*'
        }],
    StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=30),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
    Period=3600,
    Statistics=['Maximum'])

Comment: The metric name in boto code has a funky looking quote at the end. Other than that, are you hitting the same CloudWatch region?

Comment: your start and end times are potentially different- can you run those with absolute times instead of datetime/timedelta?
Can you also check the region you are hitting against?

Comment: Thanks a lot @srodriguez, I did update the answer below. But the pointers you mentioned are helpful nonetheless.